# Prevent Process Kill From Task Manager, Reversed

Tags: windows, delphi, taskmanager

I use the code below to prevent the user from killing my program from Task Manager (I found it somewhere):

```
function PreventProcessKill: Integer;
var
  hProcess:Thandle;
  EmptyDacl: TACL ;
  pEmptyDacl: PACL ;
  dwErr : DWORD ;
begin
  hProcess := GetCurrentProcess();
  ZeroMemory(@EmptyDacl, SizeOF(tacl));
  pEmptyDacl := @EmptyDacl;
  if (not InitializeAcl(EmptyDacl, sizeof(tACL), 2)) then dwErr := GetLastError()
  else dwErr := SetSecurityInfo(hProcess, SE_KERNEL_OBJECT, DACL_SECURITY_INFORMATION, nil, nil,
  @EmptyDacl, nil);
  Result:= dwErr;
end;
```

It works great, but at some point in my program I need to revert the effect and allow closing from Task Manager.
Any ideas?

Comment: Which uses do i need?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I finally found it. I can call SetSecurityInfo, passing nil instead of an empty DACL. It seems that an empty DACL means "No permissions" and a null DACL means "All permissions".

Comment: You asked how to revert the change you made. The approach outlined here does not do that. Therefore it does not answer the question that you asked.

Comment: And what's more, not only does it not revert the change, it grants total access to everyone. Read this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms717798.aspx

Answer (score 6):

You are modifying the DACL when you call SetSecurityInfo. So, just before you do that call GetSecurityInfo and make a note of the original process DACL. When the time comes, call SetSecurityInfo again to restore it.

Do note that a determined user can also do this so you cannot actually stop them from killing the process. You are just making it a little awkward.